# Switching characters unpauses the game

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I often pause the game to get a better overview or to issue commands to the other characters. However, switching characters sometimes automatically unpauses the game, which is very annoying. I have yet to discover a pattern how and when this happens...

Is this a bug, or is there some mechanic that I do not fully understand? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you using the tactics mode, or just pausing the game to bring up the action wheel?

Comment: @cbirdsong No tactics mode, just pressing "ctrl" (on PC).

Comment: On a gamepad on PC, I notice that whenever it's paused but not in tactics mode, it sometimes unpauses momentarily, but if I enter tactics mode I can skip around queuing up orders like you'd expect. Try that?

Answer (score -1):

More than likely it is a bug, as it was not this way with previous Dragon Age games. Report it to the developers, and it may be fixed come the next patch

Comment: `as it was not this way with previous Dragon Age games`. So Inquisition not being like the previous 2 games means Inquisition is a bug itself?

Comment: The whole idea with the Dragon Age games, to me, is it is slightly the same as the Dungeons and Dragons style games itself. While there aren't as clearly defined "turns" for combat, you can still take as much time as you need to queue up moves so that all of your characters can be performing the moves you want them to in real time, rather than a hectic jump from one to another, ultimately making characters not reach their full potential. With DOI, being a newly released game, it is highly probably that it is a bug in the code rather than a design feature.